# Optmizing table comparisons (joins) query in sqlite 3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have two tables `audio` and `folder` with following schema

AUDIO

```
-------------------------------
ID | NAME | FILESIZE | FID
-------------------------------
```

FOLDER

```
-------------------------
ID | NAME
-------------------------
```

Audio table holds the audio files scanned from device and folder table holds the folder of the file.
Now I want content change detection,to determine if there is any new song adde/deleted from the device, in subsequent scan of the device. So I have two replica tables `newaudio` and `newfolder`.

So for comparison I am running the following query

```
select case
when (select count(audio.id) from audio,newaudio where audio.filesize=newaudio.filesize and audio.name=newaudio.name and (select name from folder where id=audio.pid)=(select name from newfolder where id=newaudio.pid))=(select count(*) from newaudio)
then 1 
else 0
end as matchResult
```

Is there any better opmtimized query to do the same thing??

**EDIT**

`Audio` and `folder` tables hold entries from the last scan.
Now when I delete or add songs and again sync the device, entries go in `newaudio` and `newfolder` tables.

So comparison is between new and old entries.

For next scan, `newaudio` and `newfolder` replace `audio` and `folder` and `new*` tables are created again, and so on

**EDIT2**

The purpose is just to detect the content change - yes or no. I am not concerned about the files which are changed.

Comment: On delete of file, the record from FOLDER table is also deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to get a list of new or changed files:

```
SELECT id, name, filesize, fid
FROM newaudio
EXCEPT
SELECT id, name, filesize, fid
FROM audio
```

Use this query to get a list of deleted files:

```
SELECT *
FROM audio
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id
                 FROM newaudio)
```

Comment: IMO these queries will be equal to scanning the tables twice one for new/changed files and one for deleted files. So I think (not sure) this will be slower as compared to my query.